# Ruby-on-Rails toggleable sidebar to edit particular item of list

Tags: css, ruby, twitter-bootstrap-3, sidebar, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a table displaying a collection of cards, one card per row. When I click on a particular row, I get redirected to the page where I can edit this card. I would like to edit them in a toggleable sidebar, which would appear on the right of my table of tasks. I have a menu on the other side, also toggleable and designed in my application layout, and I tried to reproduce and customize it inside of the cards' index view, but it didn't work.

First, would I do that with a modal, or an actual sidebar ? How to change the content dynamically, according to the parameters, should it contain a partial ?

I am a bit lost on the way to do it, if anyone has ever done something similar or could help me, I would really appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a partial that contains the usual `form_for` element, with the right text boxes and error messages and so on. But in the `index` controller action for this page (I assume it's something like `cards_controller#index`), you'll need to set up an instance variable with the empty model for the `form_for` to use.

Then you'll need to decide how the card will be submitted. If you're okay with a page reload, it can submit to the `cards_controller#create` or `cards_controller#update` actions... but those actions will want to redirect back to the `index` view if successful. It may be easier with an AJAX request. You'll have the form submit back to the same actions, but use a `respond_to` block. When the request is a json type, submit the right status code, and respond on the page appropriately.

Good luck!

Comment: I already use that for creating a card. I got an input above my table, and if you submit a text in it will reload the cards list, which is a partial. For that, as you said, I needed to create a new empty instance of card to work in the index controller. My main problem with the edit is the design it has to have, the sidebar. The only way I know to implement properly a sidebar is to put it in the layout, so that it is generated before the content of the page itself and it interacts well with it, in a responsive way.

Comment: The problem is that I don't want the layout to be refreshed each time, whereas I need to change the variables into the sidebar, and they will even be empty at the beginning so I have to put a if around this sidebar in the layout so that I don't get an error. It is mainly a design problem I guess, it consists in adding a sidebar to the layout on an action, and to pass it parameters. I think I would render a partial inside of the sidebar, but still I have to give it parameters to pass them as locals. I don't know if I'm clear here ?